# How can I close a window after using Turtle

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder, turtle-graphics

I am trying to use Turtle in Spyder and Jupyter but I am having trouble when I try to close the window.

I am using Python 3.7 on Spyder 3.3.1 and Jupyter 5.6.0, on Windows 10

This is what I have tried

```
import turtle as trtl

trtl.forward(100)
trtl.left(90)
trtl.forward(100)
trtl.left(90)
trtl.forward(100)
trtl.left(90)
trtl.forward(100)
trtl.exitonclick()
```

I works fine, but if I close the window and try to run the same code again, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Terminator                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ad2d84897daf> in <module>()
      1 import turtle as trtl
      2 
----> 3 trtl.forward(100)
      4 trtl.left(90)
      5 trtl.forward(100)

~\Anaconda3\lib\turtle.py in forward(distance)

Terminator:
```

I have tried multiple combinations of `done()`,`bye()` and `exitonclick()` but I cannot make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late, but I think that the best option to solve this problem in Jupyter is:

```
import importlib
import turtle
importlib.reload(turtle)

turtle.forward(1)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

The problem is that the TK Application is created in the `import turtle` and terminated when you invouce to `bye` when clicking in the window. When you try to execute some turtle instruction after that, the TK Application is terminated and then the error take place. So reloading the turtle package solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from the turtle [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.exitonclick):

> If the value “using_IDLE” in the configuration dictionary is False (default value), also enter mainloop. Remark: If IDLE with the -n switch (no subprocess) is used, this value should be set to True in turtle.cfg. In this case IDLE’s own mainloop is active also for the client script.

Thus, you can add `using_IDLE = True` to [`turtle.cfg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#how-to-configure-screen-and-turtles) file to solve this issue. This will prevent `exitonclick()` to enter the mainloop.

Comment: Than you for the answer, but that did not fix the problem. Now I get a different error that I cannot post here for lack of space, but it's again an error about the terminator with no more information:
    
    File ".../test.py", line 3, in <module>
        trtl.forward(100)

      File "<string>", line 5, in forward
    
    Terminator

Comment: Hey @jrglez, you can try providing `-n` in the _Configure per file >> command line options_ in spyder. But, I don't think it'll work either. If nothing works, you can always choose _Configure per file >> Execute in external system terminal_. But, again that doesn't solve the original problem. And, Feel free to add your own answer if you find one.

Comment: Thanks, the second option seems to work on Spyder. But is there any way to do something similar in Jupyter?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in jupyter as what the second option is doing is to simply call `python <filename.py>` from system terminal, which isn't possible in jupyter. As a turnaround, you can still save jupyter notebook as python file then execute it.